# Declare SimpleXMLElement without data?

Tags: php, simplexml

I have a cron script which reads a curl response into a SimpleXMLElement.

Recently after running smoothly for over a month I began to get emails from cron with errors like:

```
Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): Entity: line 4: parser error : XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document in ...
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'String could not be parsed as XML' in ...
Stack trace:
#0 /home/cronscript.php(220): SimpleXMLElement->__construct('<?xml version="...')
#1 {main}
```

Is this related to a bad response?  If not, why would it suddenly start throwing errors like this?

And finally, how can I declare the SimpleXMLElement beforehand as it suggests?  All the examples on php.net only declare it at time of use.  Can I declare it first and then supply the data afterward?  What would be the proper way to do this?

Comment: Personal curiosity: What's the point of having an empty object designed to parse XML so that you can add the XML later?  Wouldn't you just make the object when you have the data?

Comment: Inspect the response string. _XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document_ implies there could be a problem like whitespace before the `<?xml` in the returned string.

Comment: @Michael - thanks.  I see I was misunderstanding the error and thought it referred to my script, not the response.  So some problem with response presumably.  Can I simply use php `strip()` to remove whitespace from the curl response?

Comment: @billynoah `trim()` would be what you want, but it could be something else too, like an error message returned as plain text instead of an XML response.  You'll need to examine the faulty responses.

Comment: I imagine you are correct, however it seems the script died before it had a chance to record the response to my log file.  At this point everything has resumed normal behaviour so I'll just assume this was a temporary problem and perhaps I'll log the response before calling SimpleXMLElement so as to catch it if it happens again.  Thanks for your insight.

Comment: Yeah.. I meant trim() not strip().